# Sorting a List Alphabetically in Python from a Certain Character

Tags: python

If I have a Python list as follows:

```
["Banana", "Dog", "00Apple", "Carrot"]
```

I know I can use `sorted(List)` to return:

```
["00Apple", "Banana", "Carrot", "Dog"]
```

But how can I sort the list starting from a certain Character? For example, I want the above list to start being alphabetically sorted from 'c', so as to return :

```
["Carrot", "Dog", "00Apple", "Banana"]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can subtract the `ord` of the first letter, then mod by 26, for example

```
>>> data = ['Carrot', 'Dog', 'Apple', 'Banana']
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda s: (ord(s[0]) - ord('C'))%26)
['Carrot', 'Dog', 'Apple', 'Banana']
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda s: (ord(s[0]) - ord('D'))%26)
['Dog', 'Apple', 'Banana', 'Carrot']
```

Strings preceded by numbers would then be sorted as follows

```
>>> data = ['Carrot', 'Dog', 'Apple', 'Banana', '123Apple']
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda s: (ord(s[0]) - ord('C'))%26)
['Carrot', 'Dog', '123Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana']
```

Comment: What happens if some of the data start with numbers?

Comment: You can modify your sort criteria however you want, if you want numbers to precede any letters than you can change the lambda to do so

Answer (score 1):

Add a designator ("C") and sort the list:

```
>>> l = ["Banana", "Dog", "Apple", "Carrot"]
>>> l.append("C")
>>> l.sort()
```

Find it:

```
>>> loc = l.index("C")
```

And then switch the list around:

```
>>> l = l[loc+1:] + l[:loc]
```

Altogether:

```
l = ["Banana", "Dog", "Apple", "Carrot"]
l.append("C")
l.sort()
loc = l.index("C")
l = l[loc+1:] + l[:loc]
print(l)
['Carrot', 'Dog', 'Apple', 'Banana']  # Output
```

Answer (score 1):

The `bisect` module is built into python and can be useful here.  With this we can sort the list alphabetically, find where `"C"` would go in the list, and then move the front of the list to the back.

```
# Setup
import bisect
threshold = "C"
lst = ["Banana", "Dog", "Apple", "Carrot"]
# Sort the list alphabetically
lst.sort()
# Find where "C" would go in the list
loc = bisect.bisect_left(lst, threshold)
# Move the front of the list to the back
lst = lst[loc:] + lst[:loc]
print(lst)
```